# How to set the content of include widget containing xml file at the bottom of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to use two buttons at the bottom of screen, for the layout of two buttons I created another xml file named frag and included that in relative layout field of main activity with alignParentButtom attribute, but that is not working.

This is my main xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<include layout="@layout/frag"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this the the frag.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CONNECT"
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DISCONNECT"
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Why this image is not according to its attribute of layout_height="wrap_content"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmOVq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this -

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<include layout="@layout/frag"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This worked but the field is occupying space of match_parent rather than wrap_content.

Question updated with screenshot of after changes suggested by you

Comment: Update the question with exactly the changes you applied.

Comment: That should not be having such issue. Remove the other views and check only the xml you posted.